# Can those RGB light strips on RAM DIMMs typically be disabled?

Tags: memory, led, rgb

These days, many of the RAM dimm modules one finds available come with gaudy, if not altogether garish, LED strips emitting either fixed-color lights or even cycling through some light pattern. But I'm buying RAM, not variety show tickets, damn it...  :-(

Anyway, if I get one of these - by any of the popular manufacturers (e.g. G.Skill, Corsair, Kingston etc.) - can I...

- Assume that lights can be stably turned off,
- Assume that lights will just be on and there's nothing I can do about it, or
- Not assume anything, and it's different by vendor and model?

Comment: just dont buy any with LED lights?

Comment: you can always switch those RGB lights off (the older "single colour" ones not so much) - each vendor probably has it's own proprietary method of doing so ... look for software called `openRGB` - it can handle 99% of them (and motherboards, GPU's, keyboards, mice, etc) - open source and free

Comment: @JaromandaX: But if I need software to do it, that means the lights will be working on boot, doesn't it?

Comment: @Keltari: The problem is that I see more and more models with those LED lights, and it doesn't look like there's always a LED-less variant.

Comment: yes and no - my RAM sticks are off ... the only time they come back on is if I power off the computer AND disconnect the power - otherwise, at least with my ram, it remembers the setting

Comment: @JaromandaX: And that's typical behavior when you buy these kind of DIMMs?

Comment: I can only speak for the ones I have of course

Comment: @einsupportsModeratorStrike I have bought many sticks of desktop RAM recently.  Not only did I buy them without LED lights, it wasnt even an option.   I am sure no matter what RAM you need, you can easily find it without LED lights.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for every brand, but I know about corsair.
I have them, and I loaded there software.

I was able to set the RGB to all black.  Now if there off, or if in fact it is generating all black I don't know.

The net result is no color.

Comment: But do you need to turn the colors off after boot? Or is is off-by-default?

Comment: They were on by default, I had to load corsair software and set them to black.  As far as I can remember they have stayed black since.

Comment: ... even after powering-off? Sorry for being nitpicky, but that's what I'm worried about: Them coming back on T_T